# Replace all characters in string apart from PHP

Tags: php, string, trim, str-replace

I have a string `Trade Card Catalogue 1988 Edition` I wish to remove everything apart from 1988.

I could have an array of all letters and do a `str_replace` and `trim`, but I wondered if this was a better solution?

```
$string = 'Trade Card Catalogue 1988 Edition';
$letters = array('a','b','c'....'x','y','z');
$string = str_to_lower($string);
$string = str_replace($letters, '', $string);
$string = trim($string);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you really want to do? Remove every character in order to filter a number from the string? Or anything else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular expression?

So assuming you want the number (and not the 4th word or something like that):

```
$str = preg_replace('#\D#', '', $str);
```

`\D` means *every character that is not a digit*. The same as `[^0-9]`.

If there could be more numbers but you only want to get a four digit number (a year), this will also work (but obviously fails if you there are several four digit numbers and you want to get a specific one) :

```
$str = preg_replace('#.*?(\d{4,4}).*#', '\1', $str);
```

Comment: You might wanna change it to `preg_replace`.

Comment: `{4}` is convenient shorthand for `{4,4}`

Answer (score 1):

You can actually just pass the entire set of characters to be trimmed as a parameter to `trim`:

```
$string = trim($string, 'abc...zABC...Z ' /* don't forget the space */);
```